# Experimental limits on anisotropies in the $e/m_{e}$ ratio

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass-spectrometry, poincare-symmetry, symmetry-breaking

Currently the charge-to-mass ratio of the electron is known to [10 orders of magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass-to-charge_ratio#The_electron).

However, i'm curious if:

1. Are there any experiments trying to bound the anisotropy of this ratio for different directions of space? Over what time does the data needs to be averaged to get to our current ten-figure precision? Less than a day? Less than a second? Less than a month?
2. Does an spatial anisotropy (or an spatial inhomogeneity) of this ratio break Poincare symmetry, or can that be restored with replacing the mass scalar with a tensor object? Also, what theoretical ideas explicitly disallow a non-scalar fundamental mass? What about a non-scalar electromagnetic charge?
3. Does mass spectroscopic experimental data bound any anisotropic variations? Do we have any measurements of this ratio on small cavities where van der waals forces are dominant?

Comment: How would You define that "directions"? Up/down east/west? In plane of ecliptic, orthogonal to ecliptic? or would You prefer plane of our galaxy as a reference?

Comment: i'm not sure, but i would expect any anisotropy to manifest by measuring variations at either a 24-hour or 1-year periods in 3 fixed axis directions at earth

Comment: Why are you asking this question? You are not giving enough input, anyway. Anisotropy versus what? the earth? the sun? the direction of motion? The very great accuracy of the measurement gives an indication that even if an anisotropy existed with respect to the direction of motion it would be within the errors of the measurements, or at least a factor of ten to the error of the measurements. Otherwise it would have been detected. If it is a gravitational space type of question new experiments would have to be planned, but for what reason? Which theory is predicting anisotropy?

Comment: @anna, no theory that i'm aware right now, but wondering how sure are we (quantitatively, and theoretically) that mass and charge are scalar constants

Comment: I'm with anna.  There are several independent measurements of the electron charge, from collider experiments to quantum hall effect experiments, and they all agree to very very high precision.

Comment: @Jerry and @anna indeed, but does the data need to be averaged over a long window of time to reach the current precision? or can we make measurements to our best precision in a small time frame? how long would be the time frame involved?

Comment: @Time frames are small. The ones in magnetic fields measure the radius of the circle and the magnetic field, however long that takes it is small because we are talking of ev electrons at least, quite fast. Less than a microsecond. Ditto for the Zeeman effect . There are many experiments in different labs at different times. A measurable space anisotropy would have given inconsistent results between different measurements. So any anisotropy, if it exists, is within errors.

Comment: "how sure are we (quantitatively, and theoretically) that mass and charge are scalar constants" . Our concept of mass has developed from classical mechanics, the same with charge. If charge and/or mass behaved differently at different times in different locations we would have noticed  experimentally and would have developed different classical mechanics and electromagnetism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask in the comments to the main question:

"how sure are we (quantitatively, and theoretically) that mass and charge are scalar constants" .

Our concept of mass has developed from classical mechanics, the same with charge and classical electrodynamics. If charge and/or mass behaved differently at different times in different locations we would have noticed experimentally and would have developed different classical mechanics and electromagnetism.

Mass and charge are assumed to be scalar in QM as  continuation of the classical mechanics attributes. The many and accurate measurements of e/m allow very little leeway to a different interpretation, within measurement errors.